# Multiple one-to-many relationship on mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to store three models of documents, sometimes I have to update references between then, for this I'm using [mongoose-relationship plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-relationship), 
My need is reference then like this:

- One customer have many schedules,
- One costumer have many orders,
- One order have many schedules

When I create an order I need to push schedules id's into order to reference then. But I can only reference one childPath per collection, my models are mapped like this;

Customers:

```
var CustomerSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    shedules: [{ type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Schedule" }],
    orders: [{ type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Order" }]
}
```

Schedules:

```
var ScheduleSchema = new Schema({
    customer: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Customer", childPath:"shedules"}, //shedule id
    order: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Order", childPath:"shedules"}, //order Id
    sequence: {type: Number, default: 0},
    creation_date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}
SheduleSchema.plugin(relationship, {relationshipPathName:['customer','order']});
```

Orders:

```
var OrderSchema = new Schema({
    customer: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Customer", childPath:"order"},
    shedules: [{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Shedule" }],// <-- this field doesn't update.
    price: {type: Number, default: 0}
}
OrderSchema.plugin(relationship, { relationshipPathName:'customer' });
```